# How to measure green/blue reflected light on EV3?

Tags: nxt, ev3, sensor-colour

As I know there is no way to turn on green/blue reflected light on EV3 color sensor.

Is there a way to do it using NXT color sensor and EV3 controller?

Or the only way is to use NXT controller together with NXT color sensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a modified Color sensor block available [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/231755180306049/).

As of this writing, [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53437658/ev3/nxtcolorblock.zip) is the most up-to-date direct link to download the block.